# Hyperlink within paragraph does not work

Tags: hyperref

When I want to put `\hyperlink` within `\paragraph` I get bunch of errors and it fails to compile:

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{\hyperlink{link_name}{sender} some text}

\hypertarget{link_name}{receiver}

\end{document}
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: `\paragraph[text for toc]{\hyperlink{link_name}{sender} some text}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks a lot, it works!

Comment: You can also use `\paragraph{\protect\hyperlink{link_name}{sender} some text}`.  The importatnt thing is to remember that a copy is being written to the aux file for possible use in the TOC.

Comment: @JohnKormylo If `\paragraph`s are bookmarked, e.g. using `\usepackage[depth=4]{bookmark}`, this would still lead to warnings.